# Xcode12.1 CODE_SIGN_ENTITLEMENTS error while archive

Tags: swift, xcode, react-native

Hi there I am new in the app development I bought an react native app and when I try to archive the build I am getting the error
The file "/path/projectname.entitlements" could not be opened.
Verify the value of the CODE_SIGN_ENTITLEMENTS build setting for target "Projectname" is correct and that the file exists on disk.
what should I do ? I am using Xcode 12

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Go to Project Settings
2. Go to Signing section
3. Set Code Signing Entitlements

Comment: I am sorry for asking again I am not sure what should I set there

Comment: You have to set your apps required entitlements, what you have to set depend on what your app or your apps dependencies require.

How to: https://help.apple.com/xcode/mac/current/#/dev88ff319e7
List of entitlements: https://help.apple.com/developer-account/#/dev21218dfd6